# What is wrong with my hash of hash code?

Tags: perl, hash

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong? I can't figure it out....
Basically what my code is trying to do is to read the files and create a hash for each file, these hashes are organized into on hash. The user would input two parameters, one is the key of the outer hash, and the other is for the one inside.
The ones I input are city and PIT; the same as the parameter I wrote before the line that breaks down....

I tried thousands of times, I keep getting this error: Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference I have commented that line out in the code.
The two files are cities.txt; school.txt.
Their content are just as below:
PIT\tPittsburgh
NY\tNewYork

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
our %hash_all = ();
sub readHash{
    my @vars = @_;
    my $filename = $vars[0];
    my %iptable = ();
    if(open(IN,$filename.".txt")) {
            while(<IN>) {   
            my @tmp = split(/\t/);
            $iptable{$tmp[0]} = $tmp[1];
        }
    }
    return %iptable;
}

sub loadAll{
        my %school = readHash("school");
    my %city = readHash("cities");
    $hash_all{school} = \%school;
    $hash_all{city} = \%city;
    print Dumper(\%hash_all);
}

 sub queryValue{
    my @pars = @_;
    my $key1 = $pars[0];
    my $key2 = $pars[1];

    print "key1".$key1;
    print "key2".$key2;
    print Dumper(\%hash_all);   
    my %temp = %{$hash_all{"city"}};#THIS LINE WORKS
    print $temp{"PIT"}; #THIS LINE WORKS
    my %temp2 = %{$hash_all{$key1}};#THIS LINE HAS AN ERROR
    print $temp2{$key2};
}

loadAll();
my $par1 = <>;
my $par2 = <>;
queryValue($par1,$par2);
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `$key1` is undefined. If you do a bit of back-tracing, you can see that `$key1` came from the first argument to `queryValue`, which was `$par1`. This is the first line of your input, so I suspect there is something wrong with how you are feeding your program input. Could you share with us your code for executing your script as well as your input file?

Comment: @Mattrition: That isn't what the error message is saying, because `$key1` isn't being used as a hash reference. The problem is that `$hash_all{$key1}` is undefined, so most likely the value of `$key1` doesn't correspond to any of the keys of `%hash_all`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that when you read in `$par1` and `$par2`, they include newlines at the end.  So you end up looking for a hash key like `"city\n"`, which is not the same as `"city"`.

Make sure you use `chomp` on your input parameters, like `chomp($par1)` .  That should take care of it.